# Pointers for getting started with SilverStripe modules

Tags: silverstripe

I am new to SilverStripe.

I would like to know a good place where I can start making modules for SilverStripe; some good tutorials to get me started.

Answer (score 12):

A SilverStripe module can do practically anything, so it's hard to say where to get started.

The following Wiki page has some *very* basic startup information:

- [SilverStripe Wiki - Creating Modules](http://doc.silverstripe.org/creating-modules)

Beyond that, I'd recommend reading up on how to use [ModelAdmin](http://doc.silverstripe.org/modeladmin) to create simple administration interfaces in the CMS, and maybe take a good look through the [API Docs](http://api.silverstripe.com) to get an idea of what is available to use.

However, there is nothing fundamentally different about modules as there is about any other site functionality (or even themes) - it all uses the same API and structure - so maybe download a few popular modules to see how they're built.

Finally, [SSBits](http://ssbits.com) is also a particularly good tips & tutorials website for SilverStripe, and the SilverStripe [Forum](http://silverstripe.org/forums/) and [IRC channel](http://irc.silverstripe.com/) are useful too.

Comment: +1 for download modules and see how they're built. I would also add leftandmain.com and in particular this post - http://www.leftandmain.com/silverstripe-tips/2010/09/27/silverstripe-development-standards-start-coding-like-a-pro/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the SilverStripe book "The Complete Guide to CMS Development", you can find it at Amazon or view it online at Google Books, it is not a complete reference but a good start to module development.
It has many examples, using a complete example project (with downloadable code) and some additional recipes for frequent tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more up-to-date resources...

Module structure:

http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/extending/modules/

Publishing modules:

http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/extending/how_tos/publish_a_module/

SilverStripe video lessons:

http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/

Answer (score 0):

If you're still unsure, I can recomment the book ["SilverStripe 2.4 Module Extension, Themes, and Widgets: Beginner's Guide"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184951500X) - targeting the current SilverStripe version.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the book, but given the title it should fit your requirements well...